# Nginx not serving the right resources

Tags: nginx

My use-case is pretty dead simple:

```
/var/www
├── public/
│   └── index.html
└── app/
    ├── css/
    ├── js/
    └── index.html
```

I want to serve `public/index.html` as a fallback landing page to any request not pointing `app/(.*)`, and serve the content of `app/` on accessing `mydomain.local/app`

What am I doing wrong with this configuration?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 192.168.0.200:80;

    server_name mydomain.local;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/public/;
    }

    location /app {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

Comment: try_files /index.html = 404; (you can change 404 for the code you want to return   The way toy are setting it if they enter mydomain.local/foo/bar nginx will search in /var/www/public/foo/bar , not simply in /var/www/public/ and then try index.html

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure where I should put this?

Comment: Inside the location / bracket. Pablo did it in his answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using try_files directive:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 192.168.0.200:80;

    server_name mydomain.local;

    index index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/public/;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /app {
        root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

Nginx will try to match $uri and if it doesn't match it will do a internal redirect to index.html

Source: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/#trying-several-options

Comment: Thank you, this works. Funnily enough, I had this exact configuration at some point - I thought my directives were wrong until I realized that when building a VueJS app for production, the default publicPath was `'/'`, thus explaining why my `GET`s on resources were messed up ...